# Why isn't the object owner also the segment owner in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Whenever I create an object in my schema, the owner of the segment is not the object owner. Please see below:

```
 1* select count(*) from dba_objects where owner='ERIC'
SQL> /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4
```

And from dba_segments:

```
  1* select count(*) from dba_segments where owner='ERIC'
SQL> /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

Comment: Did you verify that your object actually has a segment? (Deferred segment creation is the default nowadays.)

Comment: I didn't confirm that. The object was a table, and I used default settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mat. I just found out that this is a feature new to 11g.

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior in 11g is to use [deferred segment creation](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2011/02/deferred-segment-creation.html).  This means that when you create a table, Oracle does not create a segment until you insert the first row.  That's very useful when you're installing a third party application that has a number of tables that will always be empty (generally because you haven't licensed or implemented whatever module those tables support)-- it prevents you from wasting a ton of space on empty segments.